# How to determine the line of javascript code which changes the url?

Tags: javascript

I have an existing site with a lot of javascript included. My javascript is adding a query string parameter (using `history.replaceState`) but right after the adding, it gets removed. How can I find the line of javascript who is removing my query string parameter? (I've been trying to place breakpoints in the Chrome dev tools on certain method calls but no luck so far.)

There is no real network navigation happening here, all changes come from javascript and angularjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps solved my problem:

First I've hijacked the `pushState` and `replaceState` methods to see when they are triggered. Everywhere where expected they were triggered. No other known calls are made. The catch is in the AngularJS `$location` component. It checks what happens `onUrlChange` and removes data which is no hash and is different from the baseUrl (as far as i can understand from checking briefly)

Answer (score 0):

With given information I can only say that its probably a redirection that must be removing your query parameter. Try enabling preserve network logs and then track the network calls to see if there are any redirections happening.

Comment: There is no real network navigation happening, all url changes are happening via javascript (combination of Angularjs and plain javascript).

Comment: In that case its very difficult for anyone here to help :( unless you post the code

Comment: Hmm, pasting the bazillion lines of javascript would do no good here. Solved my issue. First hijacked the `pushState` and `replaceState` methods to see when they are triggered. Everywhere where expected they were triggered. No other known calls are made. The catch is in the angularjs `$location` component. It checks what happens onUrlChange and removes data which is no hash and is different from the baseUrl (as far as i can understand from checking briefly)